# How to map stored procedures having dynamically pivoted fields

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which gets `pivot` fields as a parameter (say `@P`) which splits by `,` 
and am pivoting for a table based on fields which the the `@P` includes them ,  i wanna map the stored procedure in `EF` . But don't know how to create a complex type with dynamic number of fields based on result of stored procedure.
I have something like the fallowing:

```
CREATE PROC pr 
@p AS NVARCHAR(500)='[250], [251], [256], [257], [260]'
AS 
DECLARE @qy NVARCHAR(500)


SET @qy='SELECT VendorID, '+dbo.SetAliasForPivotingCols(@p)+'
        FROM 
        (SELECT PurchaseOrderID, EmployeeID, VendorID
        FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader) p
        PIVOT
        (
        COUNT (PurchaseOrderID)
        FOR EmployeeID IN
        ( '+@p+' )
        ) AS pvt
        ORDER BY pvt.VendorID;
EXEC sp_executesql @qy
```

To attach alias after pivoted fields (imagine im not doing this if its complex) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SetAliasForPivotingCols](@RequestedRscsId NVARCHAR(500))RETURNS `NVARCHAR(2000)`
BEGIN
SET @RequestedRscsId=','+@RequestedRscsId
DECLARE @ReturnValue NVARCHAR(2000)=''
DECLARE @CloseBraceIndex INT
DECLARE @Alias NVARCHAR(10)
WHILE LEN(@RequestedRscsId)>1
BEGIN
    SET @CloseBraceIndex=PATINDEX('%]%',@RequestedRscsId)
    SET @Alias=SUBSTRING(@RequestedRscsId,2,@CloseBraceIndex-1)
    SET @RequestedRscsId   =SUBSTRING(@RequestedRscsId,@CloseBraceIndex+1,LEN(@RequestedRscsId)-@CloseBraceIndex+1)
    SET @ReturnValue+=',SUM('+@Alias+')'+' AS '+SUBSTRING(@Alias,1,LEN(@Alias))
END
RETURN SUBSTRING(@ReturnValue,2,LEN(@ReturnValue))
END
```

any suggestion?

thank you.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat:thanx Mitch Wheat take a look plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You must consume such stored procedure with classic ADO.NET.

Comment: so is there any way to attach the stored procedure (which maybe is written using classic ado.net) to my data model as a function? thanx.

Comment: "Attaching SP to model as a function" = mapping stored procedure. In EF it is called Function import and it has some limitations - one of limitation is static structure of returned data. So the answer is sitll no. You can create your own function in partial class for context to wrap your ADO.NET logic.